# Custom score in Elastic Search

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, pyes

I have an index, where each document represents a class, with list of students and a list of teachers.

Here is the mapping:

```
{
"properties" :  {
    "students" : {
        "include_in_root" : 1,
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "first" : "text",
                "last" : "text",
                },
            },
            "email" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        },

    "teachers" : {
        "include_in_root" : 0,
        "include_in_all" : 0,
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "title" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
                "first" : "text",
                "last" : "text",
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

I would like to influence Elastic Search score function, such that it will give higher score to documents with matched **techers**.

For example, if I have search for "Smith", I would like the documents with **teacher** Smith be with higher score than documents with students Smith.

Does anyone knows how it should be done in Elastic Search?
In other words, how can I return the results ordered by some logic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answered here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!search/%22Use$20a$20bool$20query$20to$20run$20two$20nested$20queries%22/elasticsearch/XTAb7eHcbqI/UgnKDh7ou48J